# Perfect Shuffle Card Permutation Problem

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm given the problem where one can perform perfect shuffles (i.e. you split the deck into halves and then interweave them) on a deck of $52$ cards (both in and out shuffles) and I am supposed to determine whether all $52!$ possible deck orderings are possible through a composition of such shuffles. I know that given only in or out shuffles you cannot do so since they are cyclic and of order $8$ and $52$ but I really have no idea how to even begin to tackle this problem of composing them. Was hoping for any hints or thoughts on as to how I should attempt this problem? Thanks!

EDIT: An out shuffle is when you interweave leaving the top card on the top while an in shuffle is when you interweave by putting the top card of the bottom half on top of the whole deck.

Comment: Not sure most readers will know what in and out shuffles are.  I, for one, have no idea.

Comment: Sorry about that! Edited.

Comment: Oh, don't apologize.  Maybe everybody but me knows.  Anyway, I am grateful to learn the definition.  Thanks!

Comment: But I am a bit confused.  Isn't it obvious that "only in" shuffles can't generate everything?  After all, in any composition of "only in" shuffles the top card never moves.

Comment: Yeah, but my question is about whether it is possible to get all permutations using a combination of both in and out shuffles.

Comment: Yeah...just trying to wrap my head around it.  So...Isn't it obvious that both permutations you describe are centrally symmetric?  In which case the group generated by the two of them would have to lie inside the group of centrally symmetric permutations.

Comment: Yikes!  Found [a good reference](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/83_05_shuffles.pdf) online.  I'm right about the central symmetry (well, the authors of that paper agree with me anyway).  But I had imagined that your shuffles generated the whole of that group, and the answer appears to be much, much worse.  But..it's not all of $S_n$.

Comment: @lulu Actually, from my reading of the paper, in this case (since $n=26\equiv 2\pmod 4$) it looks like the shuffles _do_ generate all of that group?

Comment: The paper lulu links states that the size of the shuffle group on $52$ cards is $2^{26}26!\approx 2.7\cdot 10^{34}$  compared to $52!\approx 8.1 \cdot 10^{67}$  That would reflect the ability to order the $26$ symmetrically located pairs and to interchange each pair independently.

Comment: (Sorry, I should be clearer - it appears in this case that the shuffles generate all of the 'centrally symmetric permutation group', the group $B_n$; I read @lulu's comment as saying that they don't even generate all of $B_n$, which they certainly seem to in this case.)

Comment: A suggestion to get started: Cut the size of the problem way down, from $n=52$ to $n=4$ and/or $n=6$, where you can, if you're patient, calculate everything explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a suggestion.

You have two permutations, and you want to find out if they generate the entire group of all permutations.

If $a$ is one permutation, and $b$ is the other, then $ab^{-1}=(1\,27)(2\,28)(3\,29)\cdots(26\,52)$. We can see that $a$ and $c=ab^{-1}$ generates the same subgroup as $a$ and $b$.

$c=ab^{-1}$ is probably easier to deal with, since its order is $2$.

Answer (score -2):

Given an initial configuration of a deck of $52$ cards, perfectly shuffling them $52$ times will take you through exactly $52$ of the $52!$ permutations on the deck. In order to hit every one of them, you must perfectly shuffle the deck and then switch the top two cards before perfectly shuffling it again. Of course you'd be doing this for several lifetimes. In the same vein, perfectly out-shuffling $52$ times, and then in-shuffling once before out-shuffling again $52$ times will indeed have the same effect as composing (or switching just the top two cards) the permutations. But again we could never experience this in hundreds of lifetimes. A computer simulation could demonstrate it perhaps. The (n-1) k-cycle has $8$ elements in its one-orbit for $n=52$, whereas the (n+1) k-cycle has $52$. This is how order is determined. There is no multiplication that can be performed on these orders to determine whether they span the full symmetric set. We can see the composition. Go through all $52$ configurations stemming from the initial position, make one alteration, repeat. Time permitting, we will see every member of S sub $52$.

Comment: Op is talking about all possible combinations of the two _distinct_ perfect shuffles; this is different from repeatedly executing a single perfect shuffle. The order of the group is much larger.

Comment: So he wants to know if there is some combination of in and out shuffles that will take him through all $52!$ permutations on the deck?

Comment: Note that the use of [interleave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleave_sequence) to describe a perfect shuffle is widely accepted.

Comment: Not widely enough for the average reader to grasp what is being discussed. Also, there is no use of it in Persi Diaconis' PhD dissertation on this exact topic. Not that he is any kind of expert. I've found more errors than you can shake a stick at in that thing. But surely you agree that interleave is confusing to the average person in this context.